# Finding and Moving Duplicate Files from two Directories using shell script

Tags: shell, centos, etl

Hey I have three folders

```
1 : Landing Folder
2 : Completed Folder
3 : Duplicates Folder
```

I want to compare the files in 1 & 2 for duplicates. If duplicates found I want to move the duplicate file to 3.

Is there any way of doing this using Shell Script?

What I've tried but to no success is using  `ls >file_names.txt`  on 1 & 2 to get their file names in text files, so that i can compare the textfiles for duplicate records. I get the list of duplicates in an echo command, cant figure out how to move them.

Comment: you want to remove the duplicate file from folder 1 and folder 2 to folder 3. Means a file should have single copy either in folder1 or folder2 or folder 3.

Comment: In my scenario, folder 1 would always have a copy of the folder 2 file of the same name. I want to move both the files to  folder 3.

Comment: if both the files are of same name and content is different then whose folder content you would prefer?

Comment: Preferably 1, but cant I move both the duplicate files to 3?  as in content from both the folders.

Comment: Folder 1 : a.txt b.txt                 Folder 2 : a.txt   >> after moving >> Folder 3 : a.txt a.txt

Comment: okay try creating two files with same name in folder 1?? if it is working then we go ahead with folder 3 having a.txt a.txt

Comment: Sorry my bad. Content from folder1 would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if file1 contains list of files in folder1 and file2 contains list of files in folder2 then below code will work

```
grep -f file1 file2 | while read line
do 
mv folder1/$line folder3
rm -f folder2/$line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Directories

all: All files (e.g 10)
some: Some files (e.g 3)

```
# make sure you are in "all" directory
for file in ./*;
do
if test -f "../some/$file then
    rm $file
fi
done
```

##### Output

The files that were common will be in some.
The files that weren't common (7 files) will be kept in "all"